# Cypress Component Testing with Vuetify - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')

Tags: cypress, vuetify.js, cypress-component-test-runner

I am trying to set up Cypress Component Testing for vuetify components. However, I do not get it working.

I narrowed it down to the most simple case with a static button. However I am getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')`.

[image]

My Setup

```js
// TestButton.vue
<template>
    <v-btn>TestButton</v-btn>
</template>
```

```js
// TestButton.cy.js
import TestButton from './TestButton.vue'

describe('<TestButton />', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    cy.mount(TestButton)
  })
})
```

```js
//support/component.js - according https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/examples#Replicating-the-expected-Component-Hierarchy
import './commands'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import { VApp } from 'vuetify'
import { mount } from 'cypress/vue2'
import { h } from 'vue'

const vuetifyOptions = {}

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component, ...args) => {
    args.global = args.global || {}
    args.global.plugins = args.global.plugins || []
    args.global.plugins.push(new Vuetify(vuetifyOptions)) 
  
    return mount(() => {
      return h(VApp, {}, component)
    }, ...args)
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example on cypress did not work for me, however I found a different setup. The below `support/component.js` works for me

```js
import { mount } from 'cypress/vue2'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { VApp } from 'vuetify/lib/components/VApp';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component, args) => {
    args = args || {};

    args.vuetify = new Vuetify(yourVuetifyOptions);

    return mount({ render: (h) => h(VApp, [h(component, args)]) }, args);
})
```